# Can't get document.getElementById("").value or document.getElementById("").innerHtml to work

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I have an HTA that has several `<input type="text">` boxes for users to enter data. I am trying to pass this data to a VBScript.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div id="tableContent" name="tableContent" style="display:block;">
<table>
  Broad Search
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Employee ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="dateInput" name="dateIDInput" size="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="employeeIDInput" name="employeeIDInput" size="8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table>
  Specific Search
  <tr>
    <th>WO Base ID</th>
    <th>Lot ID</th>
    <th>Split ID</th>
    <th>Sub ID</th>
    <th>Operation</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="woBaseIDInput" name="woBaseIDInput" value="" size="7"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="woLotIDInput" name="woLotIDInput" value="" size="3"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="woSplitIDInput" name="woSplitIDInput" value="" size="3"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="woSubIDInput" name="woSubIDInput" value="" size="3"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="woOpInput" name="woOpInput" value="" size="3"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the VBScript:

```vb
'The following code retrieves the user supplied data.
Set woBaseIDInput = document.getElementById("woBaseIDInput")
Set woLotIDInput = document.getElementById("woLotIDInput")
Set woSplitIDInput = document.getElementById("woSplitIDInput")
Set woSubIDInput = document.getElementById("woSubIDInput")
Set woOpInput = document.getElementById("woOpInput")
Set dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput")
Set employeeIDInput = document.getElementById("employeeIDInput")
Set outputTableElement = document.getElementById("outputTable")

'The following code will sanitize user input. Only numbers and characters are allowed.
stringsToCheck = Array(woBaseIDInput, woLotIDInput, woSplitIDInput, woSubIDInput, woOpInput, dateInput, employeeIDInput)
Set regExp = New RegExp
regExp.IgnoreCase = True
regExp.Global = True
regExp.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9]" 'Add here every character you don't consider as special character

woBaseIDClean = regExp.Replace(woBaseIDInput.innerHtml, "")
woLotIDClean = regExp.Replace(woLotIDInput.innerHtml, "")
woSplitIDClean = regExp.Replace(woSplitIDInput.innerHtml, "")
woSubIDClean = regExp.Replace(woSubIDInput.innerHtml, "")
woOpClean = regExp.Replace(woOpInput.innerHtml, "")
dateClean = regExp.Replace(dateInput.innerHtml, "")
employeeIDClean = regExp.Replace(employeeIDInput.innerHtml, "")
```

The problem is `woBaseIDClean` and all of it's friends (towards the bottom of the VBS code block) aren't being populated with the data from the HTML fields.

I've tried using `.innerHtml` and `.value`, both of which don't work. I've noticed that sometimes it seems using `.innerHtml` sets the variable to an object?

`.value` does nothing (I think).

When I use `.outerHtml` I get the entire element, tags and all, as expected.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the user supplied data into my VBScript?

I would like to use the data inputted to the HTML page in a crafted SQL query.

Comment: `input` elements don't have `innerHTML`, retrieve `value` instead in `regExp`s.

Comment: Thanks. That runs without producing any errors, but the variables also don't have any values. They are all blank and do not contain the data from the text field.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my answer!

As "Teemu" posted, innerHtml won't work. I switched all of those to .value, which wasn't throwing errors, but also wasn't carrying the values from the HTML to the VBS.

I went back to my VBS script and enclosed almost the entire thing in a Sub Main, and then went back and added an onclick event to the submit button in HTML to call Main(). NOW the variables are populated with the data from the text field.

So what was happening was the HTA would load and call in the VBS scripts when it hits . The VBS scripts load and all of their code executes, but at runtime the elements that it's checking .value for aren't populates, so neither are the variables.

By enclosing the logic in a sub and calling the sub AFTER the fields are filled out, the code executes and finds the fields now populated.